# Suspend not working on Asus r558q laptop on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: suspend, asus, hibernate, lid

As in topic, when i suspend my laptop by closing the lid it never starts up again. Just shows me a blank screen. I need to hard reset my laptop to get it to work. Laptop is brand new, aswell as the system. I didn;t have the problem right away, it might have something to do with switching from integrated intel graphics card to nvidia 940mx. I tried few solutions, nothing working so far.

EDIT
Definietly something with nvidia graphics card. Changed back to intel and it's working. Is there any solution?